# Recommended book/framework for fantasy worldbuilding

Tags: magic, worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources

I have been following worldbuilding for quite sometime. I am writing a fiction with a setup from ancient Indian mythology. It is an alternate universe where Aryans have dominated all the continents and then somebody in a small town discovers the magic. There are so many ideas I am having but all I need is some kind of a framework or some book which can be followed to create the world. Basically I am looking for some book so that I can organize all the ideas in order to build a magic realism.

Comment: Are you looking for a book to guide your ideas, or a way to organize your thoughts?

Comment: Very broad, but with developing your magic check this out first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandon_Sanderson#Sanderson.27s_Laws

Comment: Please note that accepting an answer when your question is less than an hour old is generally discouraged. Doing so may deter others from providing answers to your question.

Comment: This is probably the most relevant answer here on the site.  http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-i-break-down-the-task-of-creating-a-world-into-manageable-chunks/76#76

Comment: On a side note a community wiki of world-building resources seems like a really good idea.

Comment: I am building some sort of CMS for world building, it is in an early, mostly planning phase though, but if you want I can give you a link to a blog of me where I'll put the first version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be beneficial for you to make a list of areas you're looking to develop.

For instance: geography, economics, magical systems, technical systems, political systems, etc.

Start brainstorming each area, just writing down whatever you come up with.
I.E.

> *Political systems:* There is a king, under the king are the Lords which are charged with making sure their districts are profitable.
>   Under them are mayors. Etc.
>   *Magic:* Magic is powered by X. You tap X by doing Y. Etc.

After you have a lot of stuff written down, then refine it, flesh it out, think through the implications. Make rules for how it should work.

Write down all your rules on paper and make sure you don't break them.
Then if you are wanting to make sure what you came up with makes sense, or if you are stuck and need an idea about a specific section of your world, make a very focused question on here.

Very broad questions won't help you.